# Computing diff of files on different branches. GitHub Server vs GIT (cli)

Tags: git, github, git-diff

Lets say you have two git branches in a git repository:

1. branch-one (lets say @ commit abc111)
2. branch-two (lets say @ commit xyz222)

Within the repository, I can verify a single file is the same in two locations by executing a git diff command from the terminal:

This can be done with git command line via the following syntax:

```
git diff abc111 xyz222 -- foo.txt
```

What I'm having problems with is when I attempt to use the GitHub server's (compare or PR) diff functionality comparing these two branches (at their respective commit-id locations).

I can go to the following URL:

```
http://<our-v2.9.0-github-appliance-url>/<repo>/abc111...xyz222
```

... and its showing differences on the file `foo.txt`

Any ideas why the github server's compare/pr functionality is showing 'diff' for the file when there should not be any?

Thanks for the assistance/pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because `<commit>..<commit>` (which is what `git diff <commit> <commit> is`) and `<commit>...<commit>` are different.

From the [`git-diff` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff.html)...

```
   git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
       This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.

   git diff [--options] <commit>..<commit> [--] [<path>...]
       This is synonymous to the previous form. If <commit> on one side is omitted, it
       will have the same effect as using HEAD instead.

   git diff [--options] <commit>...<commit> [--] [<path>...]
       This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second
       <commit>, starting at a common ancestor of both <commit>. "git diff A...B" is
       equivalent to "git diff $(git-merge-base A B) B". You can omit any one of
       <commit>, which has the same effect as using HEAD instead.
```

You're doing `<commit>..<commit>` on the command line and `<commit>...<commit>` in the URL.

Comment: Staring me right in the face the whole time in the URL!  If I had enough reputation I'd upvote. Thank you.